# How to pass data in flutter without change screen/page?

Tags: flutter

in a Screen, I have a value from other screen named valueAbstractAll. In same screen, I want to call the value. I use it to filter list in CustomListView class. But it shows error "undefined name". How to solve it?

```
class AbstractScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final Spacecraft valueAbstractAll;

  AbstractScreen({Key key, this.valueAbstractAll}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AbstractScreenState createState() => _AbstractScreenState();
}
class _AbstractScreenState extends State<AbstractScreen> {
.....
}

class CustomListView extends StatelessWidget {


  final List<SpacecraftAbstract> spacecrafts;

  CustomListView(List<SpacecraftAbstract> spacecraftsAbstract,) :
        spacecrafts = spacecraftsAbstract.where((SpacecraftAbstract)
       => SpacecraftAbstract.id_conference == valueAbstractAll.id)
           .toList();

  Widget build(context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: spacecrafts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
        return createViewItem(spacecrafts[currentIndex], context);
      },
    );
  } ..............
```

Comment: get the value, valueAbstractAll.id .  to filter list data in CUstomListview class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get some parameters of class A within class B, you need to have an instance of class A inside B.

You can create an object of A, or pass it with the B constructor,...

for example:

```
class AbstractScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final Spacecraft valueAbstractAll;

  AbstractScreen({Key key, this.valueAbstractAll}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AbstractScreenState createState() => _AbstractScreenState();
}
class _AbstractScreenState extends State<AbstractScreen> {
.....
}

class CustomListView extends StatelessWidget {

//here I create the instance of AbstractScreen, you can initialize abstractScreen on constructor
AbstractScreen abstractScreen = new AbstractScreen();

  final List<SpacecraftAbstract> spacecrafts;

  CustomListView(List<SpacecraftAbstract> spacecraftsAbstract,) :
        spacecrafts = spacecraftsAbstract.where((SpacecraftAbstract)
       => SpacecraftAbstract.id_conference == abstractScreen.valueAbstractAll.id /*get valueAbstractAll of AbstractScreen instance*/ )
           .toList();

  Widget build(context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: spacecrafts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
        return createViewItem(spacecrafts[currentIndex], context);
      },
    );
  } ..............
```

Comment: i get error Receiver: null, Tried calling: id  in my device

Comment: when implement in widget Text using '${widget.valueAbstractAll.id} 'in _AbstractScreenState class, it can show the value

Comment: @ediprast Because you have to set the initial value to the valueAbstractAll.

Comment: how to initial value? i'm not really understand. i am a beginner

Comment: @ediprast final Spacecraft valueAbstractAll = Spacecraft();